# Scheme: return 10 if a function returns true

Tags: scheme, return

I'm trying to implement a part where if my separate function 'write?' (which returns true or false) returns true, I want it to return the number 10.

```
(define value 
  (lambda (p gs) 
    (cond 
     ((write? p gs) #t)
     10 
     else 0)))
```

I know this is not correct because I'm getting errors, but this is the skeleton of it. 
I wanted it to do if write? with those parameters returns true, then have value return 10. 
If not, return 0.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(cond
  ((write? p gs) 10)
  (else 0))
```